# После get запроса на путь к картинке что в бд не выводит картинку.

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Сразу извиняюсь что пложу вопросы:)Храню в бд путь к картинке что на сервере,вывожду этот путь в `<img v-bind:src="srcToProdImage" alt="">`
Вот пример пути `http://localhost:8081/uploads/1528909933677-layer-2.8d64e52.png`
Получаю вот такую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Но если просто перейти по ссылке то работает!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И у меня возникает вопрос "Как так то а?".

Код
Продукт

```
<template>
  <div class="main">
    <img v-bind:src="srcToProdImage" alt="">
    <p class="name">{{ name }}</p>
    <p class="price"><span>{{ price }}</span><span></span></p>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.main{
  img{
    width: 240px;
  }
}
.name{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #222222;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.price{
  span:first-child{
    color: #f16d7f;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;

  }
}
</style>

<script>
export default {
props:["name","price","srcToProdImage"],
}
</script>
```

Компонент в котором выводятся продукты

```
<template>
  <div class="main">
    <p class="title"><span>Fetured Items</span><br>
    <span>Shop for items based on what we featured in this week</span></p>
    <div v-if="products && products.length" class="content">
      <content-item v-for="product in products" :key="product.id"
      v-bind:name="product.name"
      v-bind:price="product.price"
       v-bind:srcToProdImage = "'localhost:8081/' + product.productImage" ></content-item>
    </div>
    <p class="cont-btn">
      <button class="btn">Browse All Product <span><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></span></button>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Content_item from './Content-item';
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data: function(){
    return{
    products:[],
    errors:[]
    }
  },
  created(){
    axios.get('http://localhost:8081/products')
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result)
      this.products = result.data.products
    }).catch((err) => {
      this.errors.push(err)
    });
  },
  components: {
    'content-item' : Content_item
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.content{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.title{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  span:first-child{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #222222;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  span:last-child{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #9f9f9f;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
.cont-btn{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.btn{
  padding: 18px 24px 18px 24px;
  background-color: #f16d7f;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было поставить `http://` в строчке `v-bind:srcToProdImage = "'http://localhost:8081/' + product.productImage"`